# Convert FILE* to ifstream C++, Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, file, android-ndk

I'm coding an Android project with an NDK C++ component and have a file that needs a lot of parsing. The NDK only allows me to get a FILE* pointer to the file that I'm dealing with, not an ifstream which has a few more convenience functions associated with it. Is there anyway to convert an FILE* (cstdio) to ifstream (iostream)?

Answer (score 6):

In general, you can **not** convert a `FILE*` to an `std::ifstream`. However, this isn't really necessary anyway: It is reasonable straight forward to create a custom stream buffer which can be used to initialize an `std::istream`. Using an `std::istream` should be sufficient because the extra functionality provided by `std::ifstream` doesn't really help with parsing anyway. As long as you don't need to use seeking, creating a stream buffer for reading from a `FILE*` is really simple. All it takes is overriding the the `std::streambuf::underflow()` function:

```cpp
class stdiobuf : public std::streambuf {
private:
  FILE *d_file;
  char d_buffer[8 * 1024];

public:
  stdiobuf(FILE *file) : d_file(file) {}
  ~stdiobuf() {
    if (this->d_file)
      fclose(this->d_file);
  }
  int underflow() {
    if (this->gptr() == this->egptr() && this->d_file) {
      size_t size = fread(this->d_buffer, 8 * 1024, 1, this->d_file);
      this->setg(this->d_buffer, this->d_buffer, this->d_buffer + size);
    }
    return this->gptr() == this->egptr()
               ? traits_type::eof()
               : traits_type::to_int_type(*this->gptr());
  }
};
```

All what remains is to initialize an `std::istream` to use a `stdiobuf`:

```
stdiobuf     sbuf(fopen(...));
std::istream in(&sbuf);
```

I just typed in the above code and currently I can't try it out. However, the basic should be correct although there may be types and possibly even a little flaw.

Comment: This needs a small modification. The third argument 'size' in this->setg() should be 'this->d_buffer + size'

Answer (score 3):

Note there isn't a way to retrieve an `std::ifstream`, but you *can* get `std::istream`.

Though not a part of standard C++, sometimes `std::basic_filebuf` exposes an extension via a [constructor which takes `std::FILE *`](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/basic-filebuf.html#idx49).

> ```
> basic_filebuf(FILE *fp, char_type *buf = 0, 
>               streamsize n = /* default size */);
> ```
>
> Constructs an object of class `basic_filebuf`, initializing the base class with `basic_streambuf<charT,traits>()`. It then calls `open(fp, buf, n)`.

The way you should use this is as follows...

```
FILE *pf = ...; /* e.g. fopen("/etc/passwd", "r") */
std::filebuf buf(pf);
std::istream stream(&buf);
```

Now, if this extension is not available, then I'm afraid there's not much you can do other than try to implement your own `std::streambuf` which implements the required work.

Comment: I tried to use the second part of your code but I got error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_filebuf<char>::basic_filebuf(FILE*&)’

----- Code:
FILE *fp = fopen("./Output_BinaryImage.pgm", "r");
std::filebuf buf(fp);
std::istream stream(&buf);

Comment: @inblueswithu read my post fully -- I address that error. It is a non-standard extension to `std::filebuf`.